# 8.10 Apostol Analytic number theory

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, characters

Solved

I am self studying analytic number theory from Tom M Apostol and got stuck on this problem on page176.

It's image:

[image]

Problem is in question 10 only.

I have proved that $f(\chi) $divides $f(\chi_{1})... f(\chi_{r}) $  but I am unable to think about how can I prove the converse.

can you please help with that?

Edit : Smallest induced modulus is called conductor and Induced Modulus: Let $\chi$ be a Dirichlet Character mod k and let d be any positive divisor of k. The number d is called an induced modulus for $\chi$ if we have $\chi$(a)=1 whenever 9a,k)=1 and a$\equiv $1 (mod d). ( Page 167 of the book.)

Comment: It might help if you state how Apostol defines "conductor."

Comment: @Barry Cipra Smallest induced modulus is called conductor.

Comment: And what is an "induced" modulus? (It will help to edit the question itself, rather than clarify in comments only. It might also help if you show your proof that $f(\chi)$ divides the product.)

Comment: Please do not include a picture of the question, but write the question itself including all necessary details (such as definitions of the ambiguous terms). This improves the search- and findability of this question.

Comment: @Ben hi you called me here, I will see the material and get back to you

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Ben Seen the answer here? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3131090/proof-verification-let-f-chi-be-the-conductor-of-chi-proof-that-f-chi?rq=1

Comment: @TeresaLisbon That will suffice . Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Ben You are welcome!